# Importing csv in android application

Tags: java, android

I've found this code on a previously answered question to import a csv in an android application, i have to import into my android application a file called data.csv, i then need to perform searches on said database, the rows as such:

178464;AA1
...

here's the code:

```
package com.cdac.qrcodescanner;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CSVFile {
    InputStream inputStream;

    public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream){
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    public List read(){
        List resultList = new ArrayList();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        try {
            String csvLine;
            while ((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] row = csvLine.split(";");
                resultList.add(row);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error in reading CSV file: "+ex);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error while closing input stream: "+e);
            }
        }
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

and here's what goes where i want to use my data:

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
List scoreList = csvFile.read();
```

i now want to use the get method to have the string after the semicolon (the value), and so i tried:

```
String i = scoreList.get(178464);
```

That prompts me with the error:

```
incompatible types:

Required: Java.lang.string
Found: Java.lang.Object
```

doing this fixed the error but made my application crash:

```
String i = (string)scoreList.get(178464);
Object i = scoreList.get(178464);
```

I'm not particularly expert with Java, but i have the feeling i'm doing something incredibly wrong and i can't for the life of me figure out what, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CSVFile.read() method, we have the following :

```
String[] row = csvLine.split(";");
resultList.add(row);
```

The resultList will be a list of arrays of strings. Each element of the list is a row of your file. Each element of the array is a value (column).

So...

```
String i = (string)scoreList.get(178464);
```

returns the 178464th line of the file. I'm assuming it will crash because you do not have 178464 lines in your files, and even if you did, the value returned should be a String[].

I'm assuming you wish to index each element by it's id (178464 in your example) and access it using this id. You should use a Map instead.

```
Map resultMap = new HashMap();
while ((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   String[] row = csvLine.split(";");
   String id = row[0];
   Integer score = Integer.parseInt(row[1]);
   resultMap.put(id, score);
}
```

Then you can access the map using the ids :

```
Integer score = resultMap.get("178464");
```

Comment: I tried changing the code to what you suggested, but trying: `String i = resultMap.get("AS881702");` still gives me the same "required string found object" error. changing string to object makes the app crash the same way.

Comment: it seems the line  `Map resultMap = csvFile.read();` makes the app crash regardless, was i wrong in changing the code of the while in my CSVFile class?

Comment: Can you provide details of the errors you are getting (Exception name, stack trace) ?

Comment: It turns out the csv file had some empty rows, thanks anyway for the help!